# Camel - Check if body is a List of entities or Simple entity

Tags: apache-camel

I need to check if JSON body received in route written in DSL, is a list of entities or a single entity and then process accordingly.

How do we check if incoming body is List or Simple Entity?

Comment: You can look at camel-jsonpath, also it depends a bit what java type your JSON body is, eg is it a java Map/List/Object or is it string, or input stream or what else.

Comment: JSON can be Java List of Objects or a Single Object. Need to figure out if List or Object

Comment: Well if the body is just java objects you can use java code to check, or some of the Camel expression languages like simple, groovy, spel etc. (eg something like java instanceof)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a [Splitter EIP](https://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) to your route. It splits by default a Collection of objects to single objects.

So if your body is a **Collection**, it produces messages with single objects. If your body is **just one object** it should simply split nothing and return the single object like any object that results from splitting.

This adds a full-blown EIP to your route, but "harmonizes" the input quite nice.